# Shiny - Access actionButton value created dinamically with random values

Tags: r, shiny

I am creating an actionButton dynamically with the label given by a random letter (simplified example). After clicking the button I would like that the label will be pasted in the Text input.

```
library(shiny)
runApp(list(ui=
        shinyUI(fluidPage(

            mainPanel(
                textInput("text", label = ""),
                div(style="display:inline-block", uiOutput("wordOneButton"))
            )
        ))
,
server=shinyServer(function(session, input, output) {
# Fill the buttons with the random letter
output$wordOneButton <- renderUI({
    actionButton("action", label = LETTERS[sample(1:length(LETTERS), 1)])})


# Include predicted word in the text after click event on button
observeEvent(input$action, {
    name <- paste0(input$text, ????????, sep = " ")   <--------------
    updateTextInput(session = session, "text", value = name)
})

})

))
```

What should I put instead of ???????. I already tried with `input$wordOneButton` and `input$action`. But the result is not what I am expecting.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you could store the letter in a [reactiveVal](https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/1.0.2/reactiveVal.html) and call that value. Working example is shown below, note that you can keep the actionButton's value the same by removing the last line of the `observeEvent`. Hope this helps!

---

[image]

---

```
library(shiny)
ui = fluidPage(

  mainPanel(
    textInput("text", label = ""),
    div(style="display:inline-block", uiOutput("wordOneButton"))
  )
)

server = function(session, input, output) {

  # reactiveVal to store our random letter.
  reval <- reactiveVal(sample(LETTERS,1))

  # Fill the buttons with the random letter
  output$wordOneButton <- renderUI({
    actionButton("action", label = reval())
  })


  # Include predicted word in the text after click event on button
  observeEvent(input$action, {
    name <- paste0(input$text, reval(), sep = " ") 
    updateTextInput(session = session, "text", value = name)
    reval(sample(LETTERS,1)) # comment this line to keep actionButton the same.
  })
}

shinyApp(ui,server)
```